# Update Apache 2.4.34 to 2.4.35 in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: apache2, ubuntu-16.04

I have tried the following first in Ubuntu Server

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

No signs of software updates in the Ubuntu Server repository.

So I went ahead with PPA with the following

```
add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/apache2
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
```

OR

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/apache2
sudo apt update
sudo apt install apache2
```

But no luck as **PPA** is having **2.4.34** as the latest one.

> NOTE: Even I restarted and check with stopping and starting my Apache2
>   server.

But seems nothing working is there any other way I can update it to the latest version. This is important as our project is stuck with a Security Assessment.

And in version 2.4.34 there is DDOS security vulnerability. And has been fixed in 2.4.35

Can anyone help me out with updating apache2, even redirects to any sites or links are welcome.

Comment: I'm stuck on version 2.4.18 with my Ubuntu 16.04 

Comment: @Crimbo did you try updating the ubuntu package library (sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade) before and after?

Comment: Yeah, even `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`. It sees no newer versions

Answer (score -2):

All you need to download this version and enjoy , just 
 install it manually https://httpd.apache.org/download.cgi